# disable updates from command line in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, updates

Is there any gsettings schema to select "Never" on

system settings->software and updates->updates->automatically check for updates

Any other command line option to disable automatic updates is right for me.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Ubuntu Update Manager's new version warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115913/disable-ubuntu-update-managers-new-version-warning)

Comment: No, that's another option.. I'm not looking for "notify me of a new ubuntu version" but for "automatically check for updates"...

Comment: Do you mean unattended-upgrades? As in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006199/66509)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from Norbert and doug I came up with this solution:

```
sudo sed -i 's/APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1"/APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0"/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Comment: Result for me on 18.04 : "can't read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades: No such file or directory", can I simply create the file? Or does it exist under another file name?

Comment: that's weird.. I have couple of machines with Ubuntu 18.04 and all of them have that file..you'd better open a new question on this..

Answer (score 31):

According to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057463/790920)

Disable apt-daily.service:

```
systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily.service
systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Or

```
systemctl disable --now apt-daily{,-upgrade}.{timer,service}
```

The annoying update notifier can be simply removed by following command:

```
sudo apt purge update-notifier-common
```

Further if you want to stop automatic security updates run

```
sudo apt purge  unattended-upgrades
```

## Ubuntu 20.04

- On Ubuntu I had some problem disabling the daily update. The update gets triggered by systemctl which triggers anacron and starts the script `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat`. I commented out the last line

  ```
  # exec /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
  ```

which stops running the update.

- Further I had also to stop the autostart of discovery by running following commands:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /etc/xdg/autostart/disable
  sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/disable
  ```

Comment: The other command seems to work...

Comment: What "other command?"

Comment: @mr.zog I'm guessing `systemctl disable --now apt-daily{,-upgrade}.{timer,service}`   @abu_bua @AleksandarPavić please confirm.

Comment: `sudo sed -e '/exec \/usr\/lib\/apt\/apt.systemd.daily/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` for commenting the exec line with sed

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no gsetting for this. In 16.04 those relevant options are set in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file

Obviously the easiest way to alter is thru Software & Updates > Updates which edits that file if you change from default.

You can edit that file manually if desired or fashion some command to set the option(s) to false ("0"

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` to disable automatic updates from the command line:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Once you have the file opened, switch off the Update-Package-Lists directive from 1 to 0 as shown below:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04 server. It created the following output:

```
Replacing config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades with new version
```

After the reconfig (disable auto-updates), 20auto-upgrades contained this:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Comment: Could you improve your answer (editing it) specifying in which version of Ubuntu you tested this solution? In this way, who reach this topic may use one solution or the other according to the Ubuntu version in own machine.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (LUbuntu) I had no easy way to do it, but to symlink to `true`:

```bsh
mv /usr/bin/update-manager /usr/bin/update-manager.bak # if needed
ln -s /bin/true /usr/bin/update-manager
```